# Change values of generic 2D array class with [][] operator

Tags: c++, arrays, generics, vector

I want to create my own class for generic 2D arrays. This is what i have so far:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T> 
class My2DArray {
private:
    vector<vector<T>> array;
    int width, height;

public:
    My2DArray() {}
    My2DArray(int w, int h) : width(w), height(h) {
        array.resize(w);
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
            array[i].resize(h);
        }
    }

    ~My2DArray() {}

    vector<T> operator[](int index) {
        return array[index];
    }

    T* at(int x, int y) {
        return &array[x][y];
    }

    int getWidth() { return width; }
    int getHeight() { return height; }
};
```

Because i have my own `[]` operator for my class, which returns a `vector<T>`, which again can be accessed by the default `[]` operator of the vector class, i hoped that my class would work just like a normal vector, but it doesn't seem so. The following shows three ways of how i can or cannot change elements of a 2D array:

```
My2DArray<int> intArray1(5, 5);
intArray1[0][0] = 2;               //does not work
cout << intArray1[0][0] << "\n";   //prints 0
/*-------------------------------------------*/
My2DArray<int> intArray2(5, 5);
*intArray2.at(0,0) = 2;            //works
cout << intArray2[0][0] << "\n";   //prints 2
/*-------------------------------------------*/
vector<vector<int>> intArray3;
intArray3.resize(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    intArray3[i].resize(5);
}
intArray3[0][0] = 2;               //works
cout << intArray3[0][0] << "\n";   //prints 2
```

Is there a way to make the `[][]` operator work for my own class or do i need to use my `.at(x,y)` function giving me a pointer and using that to modify a value?

Comment: You're missing the second overload of `operator []` that will allow `const My2DArray` to be able to use `[ ]`.  Also, you should *not* be using extraneous variables like `width` and `height` in this case.  You're using a `vector`, and a `vector` knows its dimensions by calling the `size()` method.  By using those extraneous variables, you're increasing the chance of bugs occurring (due to not updating the width and height variables).  Thus your constructor could simply be: `My2DArray(int w, int h) : array(w, std::vector<int>(h)) { }` without any loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator[]` returns a fresh copy of your matrix column, very inefficient and not allowing to modify the matrix. If you want to access real matrix elements, change the return type of the method to reference:

```
vector<T> &operator[](size_t index) {
    return array[index];
}
```

(`size_t` makes more sense as the type for index for you probably don't want negative indices.)

BTW, array itself would better be initialized to the proper sizes:

```
My2DArray(size_t w, size_t h) : width(w), height(h), array(w, vector<T>(h)) {}
```

rather than first default-constructed, and then additionally changed in ctor body.